# Multi-tiered Spring application dependency resolution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a three-tier application with Spring, `view`, `logic`, `data`, more or less. The `view` depends on `logic` which depends on `data`.

How can I configure the Spring application in the `view` project such that the dependency graph is able to be resolved?

For example:

In the `view` layer:

```
@Controller
public class SomeView {
  private final SomeService someService;

  @Autowired
  public SomeView(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService = someService;
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

In the `logic` layer:

```
@Component
public class SomeService {

  private final SomeData someData;

  @Autowired
  public SomeService(SomeData someData){
    this.someData = someData;
  }

}
```

In the `data` layer:

```
@Component
public class SomeData {

}
```

This configuration is not able to boot because `SomeService` can't resolve `SomeData` because `SomeData` is not scanned in the `view` layers `Application.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `@SpringBootApplication` Spring boot uses default values. If you take a look at the [@SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) definition you will see that :

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated with @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan. Since these annotations are so frequently used together (especially if you follow the best practices above), Spring Boot provides a convenient @SpringBootApplication alternative.
>
> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their default attributes: [...]

That means :

```
@SpringBootApplication // same as @Configuration    @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also, it means that when using default values for `@ComponentScan` your packages sturctures shloud be as following :

- com.example.model -> your entities
- com.example.repositoriy -> your repositories
- com.example.controller -> controllers
- com.example -> MainApplication class

If not following this structure you should tell to the `@ComponentScan` the package where to find the components :

**Example 1:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.controller","com.my.package.domain"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Exemple 2 :**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {SomeService.class, SomeData.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also, i advice you to check this [guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) on how to structuring your code in a Spring Boot Application.

Comment: This is interesting and I think it solves my issue, but I'm having a bit of trouble still.  If I move `Application` to `com.example.something` (where all other dependencies are in `com.example.something` as well) it works; however, if I leave it in `com.example.something.else` with `ComponentScan({"com.example.something"})` it does not work.  Shouldn't that be the same thing?

Comment: What are you leaving in the com.example.something.else package, the Application.cass or the other classes. The should be fine because it remains the same thing. Also see my edit for the additional solution.

Comment: If this solves your issue then accept it. For me to know and for other to help :)